# Rotating the view within an image, not the image itself?

Tags: html, css, transform

I've been trying to recreate the banner from www.reddit.com/r/atheism with no luck

So far I'm here (fiddle to show: http://jsfiddle.net/RBhyC/):

```
#masthead {
background: url('http://d.thumbs.redditmedia.com/P622S0lrDyRKOFO3.png') no-repeat scroll 0% 0% #000;
margin-bottom: 5%;
padding: 1%;
text-align: center;
-webkit-animation:rotate 900s linear infinite;
-moz-animation:rotate 900s linear infinite;
animation:rotate 900s linear infinite;
}

@-ms-keyframes rotate { from { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); } to { -ms-transform:       rotate(360deg); }}
@-moz-keyframes rotate { from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); } to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate { from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); } to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }}
```

But right now it's just the banner that is moving, not the 'view'.. Does anyone know how to keep it in place and only rotate within the image?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle that we can see?

Comment: Done! It's in the main post too now: http://jsfiddle.net/RBhyC/

Comment: not quite sure what you need. but how is this http://jsfiddle.net/RBhyC/1/?

Comment: this is exactly what I am looking for! What exactly made it change? is it the fact that image is not in the banner class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't rotate the 'view' of an image, only the image itself.
To get the desired effect you need a container to crop the rotating image.

**The HTML**

```
<div class="banner">
    <img class="image" src="http://d.thumbs.redditmedia.com/P622S0lrDyRKOFO3.png" alt="" width="1000" height="500">
</div>
```

**The CSS** for the container

```
.banner {
    position: relative;
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RBhyC/1/)

Comment: although this works, you are restricted to height of the .banner div, below example is basically replica, that will allow you to put whatever to the .banner and it will resize appropriatelly

Answer (score 0):

try this instead, the example link uses pseudo class ::after to apply the styles to, not the image element itself, with the above solution you are restricted to size of the banner element, with this one the banner will resize appropriatelly to the content

```
<div id="somediv"><p>SOMETHING</p><p>another somethinbg</p></div>

<style>

    @-webkit-keyframes ROTATE{from{-webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg)}to{-webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(360deg)}}@keyframes ROTATE{from{transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg)}to{transform:scale(1) rotate(360deg)}}

    #somediv * {position:relative;z-index:5;}

    #somediv {
        background: transparent;
        background-size: 250px 250px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 0px!important;
        overflow: hidden;
        width:100%;
    }

    #somediv::after {
        content: "";
        color:#FFF;
        width: 2200px;
        height: 2200px;
        position:absolute;
        top: -1070px;
        left: -1100px;
        -webkit-animation-name: ROTATE;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 900s;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-name: ROTATE;
        animation-duration: 900s;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        background: #000 url("http://d.thumbs.redditmedia.com/P622S0lrDyRKOFO3.png") no-repeat;
    }
</style>
```

hope it helps

T